# Printing directly from an emacs buffer works but the printed document does not print unicode characters

Tags: print, utf-8

I run Emacs 29 in Windows. These print settings allow me to print directly from a buffer:

```
;; Printer settings
;; Set printer name to true (t) for default printer
;; (setenv "GS_LIB" "C:/gs10.01.2/lib;C:/gs10.01.2/Resource/Font")
(setq ps-printer-name t)
;; Define the printing command path, here we are using Ghostscript
(setq ps-lpr-command "C:/gs10.01.2/bin/gswin64c.exe")
;; Define the command-line switches used when calling Ghostscript:
;; "-q" to suppress prompts,
;; "-dNOPAUSE" to avoid pausing between pages,
;; "-dBATCH" to run in batch mode,
;; "-sDEVICE=mswinpr2" to use Microsoft Windows printer device,
;; "-sPAPERSIZE=a4" to set the paper size to A4
(setq ps-lpr-switches '("-q" "-dNOPAUSE" "-dBATCH" "-sDEVICE=mswinpr2" "-sPAPERSIZE=a4"))
;; Set the font size for the body text and title, both are 12 points
(setq ps-font-size '(12 . 12))
;; Set the right margin for printing to 50 points (~0.69 inches)
(setq ps-right-margin 50)
;; Set the left margin for printing to 30 points (~0.42 inches)
(setq ps-left-margin 30)
;; Define a global keyboard shortcut "C-c p" to send the buffer to the printer
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c p") 'ps-print-buffer)
```

Printing works fine but the final documents prints an em-dash as ? and smart quotes as ?. The files are unicode and my encoding is unicode.

To get the files to print I have to convert to ASCII.

Any ideas on how to solve the print problem would be appreciated.

BTW I can print using MS Word (using the solution here: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrintUsingWord) and then there is no problem with Unicode.

Comment: "To get them to print I have to convert to ASCII." - how do you do that?

Comment: That sounds like a bug in Ghostscript if you ask me. Are you sure that it supports Unicode? What happens if you use Ghostscript to print your document from the command line, without using Emacs at all?

Comment: I convert these unicode characters to something ascii understands: em-dash to dash and smart quotes to straight quotes

Comment: I tried different versions of ghostscript, but the same problem.